# What happens while wrapping and unwrapping an optional in Swift?

Tags: swift, swiftype

When a `var` is marked as an optional Swift wraps it and when actual value is needed unwrapping is performed.

```
var anOptional : String? = "wrapping"
print("\(anOptional!)  unwrapping")
```

What actually  happens during wrapping and unwrapping of an optional?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An Optional is an enum with two possible cases, `.None` and `.Some`. The `.Some` case has an associated value which is the wrapped value. To "unwrap" the optional is to return that associated value. It is as if you did this:

```
let anOptional : String? = "wrapping"
switch anOptional {
case .Some(let theString):
    println(theString) // wrapping
case .None:
    println("it's nil")
}
```

Comment: I executed the code in Playground and you are right that optional is an enum. Would you like to comment on line 3rd line of code where associated value of anOptional is being assigned to theString.

Comment: Standard syntax for obtaining associated value from enum case, see docs. https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Enumerations.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH12-XID_225

Comment: I did not mean syntax, I was just curious to know does the Swift do the same to unwrap an optional( using switch case)?

Comment: I don't understand the question. What does it mean to ask what a language "does"? You know that the exclamation mark syntax means to unwrap an optional, and you know what an optional is - what more do you want? Are you asking for assembler code? You can explore that as well I can, perhaps better than I can.

Answer (score 1):

Optional is simple variable as others but the thing is it may have two values either the value in optional variable  may be `nil` or "some value". For Example:

```
var anOptional : String?
println(anOptional) //nil

println(anOptional!) //error as optional has no value and we are trying to wrap it and getting the value

anOptional = "it has some value";

println(anOptional!) //"it has some value" as it has value and we are wrapping it
```

Here is the link for unwrapping process  http://appventure.me/2014/06/13/swift-optionals-made-simple/

Comment: Thanks for your response but this is something which I new, I was interested in unwrapping process.

Comment: yeah i have edited my answer please see it if it is useful.Thank you.